How do I change the spy glass scope using custom model data?
I am making a datapack that adds custom spyglasses, and I need to change the zoom-in overlay for each type. I have searched the internet and looked for a spyglass_scope.json in the vanilla pack, but it does not exist.
I found assets/minecraft/textures/misc/spyglass_scope.png. The problem is that there is only one spyglass_scope.png, and changing that changes the scope for all spyglasses. I need it to change for only the custom ones.

Thank you, Mr. Galacticninja, for editing this question so that it is easier to read.

After looking through some resource packs which modify the spyglass overlay, there only seems to be assets/minecraft/textures/misc/spyglass_scope.png.
More searching shows that this does not seem to be possible through through OptiFine CIT/CEM either.

Yes, I found that... the problem is that there is only one spyglass_scope.png, and changing that changes the scope for all spyglasses. I need it to change for only the custom ones. Can you attach custom textures to the overlay, like or with custom model data?

@RyCoRobot I don't believe there is a way to do this otherwise. I searched up if it was possible to do it with Optifine CIT/CEM (Custom Item/Entity Models) but it does not seem to be a thing.

Yeah, I'm starting to lose hope on this one, too. Even if the answer is "NOPE, you just can't do that," I would like to keep this up so that if someone else tries this, they will know it can not be done.

I'll update my answer accordingly.

Thanks so much!
